# Copiar elementos no presentes en una tabla de postgresql desde varios ficheros csv

Tags: python

Me encuentro desarrollando un trabajo relacionado con el almacenamiento en una tabla creada en postgresql, de registros presentes en varios ficheros csv.
El problema es específicamente el siguiente:
Tengo cientos de ficheros csv y quisiera pasar el contenido de estos a una tabla de postgres. Para ello me estoy auxiliando del módulo Pandas y el método de la clase  `DataFrame` denominado `to_sql()`.
El problema radica en que algunos ficheros contienen además de sus propias mediciones, mediciones repetidas que también pertenecen a otros ficheros. Cuando esto sucede ese fichero no se lee y yo necesito que se lea las mediciones sin duplicados.
Acá va el código.

```
from os import listdir, altsep, walk
from datetime import datetime
from time import time
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

inicio = time()
# *-----------------------------Conexión a la BD-----------------------------
url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5433/mareas_database'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)
name_date_station = pd.read_sql_query(
    "Select digital_file_code, date_sync from app_vermar_api_station join app_vermar_api_date_sync on app_vermar_api_station.id=app_vermar_api_date_sync.id_station where digital_file_code is not null", engine)
dict = name_date_station.set_index('digital_file_code').T.to_dict('list')
# *--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ruta_inicial = '../../directorio'  # * obtiene ruta
carpetas = listdir(ruta_inicial + altsep)
for key in dict:
    date = str(dict.get(key)[0])
    year = date.split("-")[0]
    month = date.split("-")[1]
    day = date.split("-")[2].split(" ")[0]
    for carpeta in carpetas:
        if carpeta.startswith(key):
            list_year = listdir(ruta_inicial + altsep + carpeta)
            for year_file in list_year:
                if year_file > year or year_file == year:
                    list_month = listdir(
                        ruta_inicial + altsep + carpeta + altsep + year_file)
                    for month_file in list_month:
                        if month_file > month or month_file == month:
                            list_day = listdir(
                                ruta_inicial + altsep + carpeta + altsep + year_file + altsep + month_file)
                            for day_file in list_day:
                                if day_file > day or day_file == day:
                                    list_files = listdir(
                                        ruta_inicial + altsep + carpeta + altsep + year_file + altsep + month_file + altsep + day_file)
                                    for j in list_files:
                                        archivo_csv = ruta_inicial + altsep + carpeta + altsep + year_file + \
                                            altsep + month_file + altsep + day_file + altsep + j
                                        data_csv = pd.read_csv(
                                            archivo_csv, header=0, delimiter=';')
                                        data_csv['CH32[V]'].fillna(
                                            0, inplace=True)
                                        data_csv.rename(columns={
                                            'Datum Zeit': 'data_datetime',
                                            'CH01[m]': 'sea_level',
                                            'CH32[V]': 'battery',
                                            'Station': 'station_rel_id'
                                        }, inplace=True)
                                        # TODO La siguiente sentencia se debe optimizar porque siempre se remplaza todo nuevamente
                                        data_csv.station_rel_id.replace(
                                            {'UCL12209': 2, 'UCL12212': 3, 'UCL12210': 5, 'UCL20049': 10, 'C03415': 17}, inplace=True)
                                        data_csv = data_csv.astype({"station_rel_id": 'int64', "battery": 'float64',
                                                                    "sea_level": 'float64', "data_datetime": 'datetime64[ns, UTC]'})
                                        try:
                                            data_csv.to_sql(
                                                name="app_vermar_api_sensor_data",
                                                con=engine,
                                                index=False,
                                                if_exists='append'
                                            )
                                        except:
                                            print(data_csv)
```

Comment: Corrigeme si me equivoco: Tienes una colecciones de mediciones (fecha,nivel,voltaje,id_estacion) dispersa a través muchos archivos .csv. Tu estructura de directorio es subdirs para año/mes/dia. Dentro del subdir dia tienes uno o más archivos con mediciones del dia.¿ Quieres obtener una lista sin repeticiones del contenido de todos los archivos del aa/mm/dd para una cierta estación?

Comment: Gracias por preguntar. Exactamente, la estructura de las mediciones es la que me comentas y la estructura del directorio es un arbol donde las ramas superiores son los nombres de las estaciones, luego para cada tipo de estación los años, los meses y los días. Dentro de la carpeta día están los archivos. Lo que sucede es que cada archivo puede contener lecturas que ya están en otro archivo (tal vez por error) y lo que quiero es pasar a una tabla de postgresql los registros sin duplicados. Saludos y gracias nuevamente por interesarse

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución a mi problema y la publico para que de alguna manera pueda servir a otros o para que sea criticada para bien. Lo que hice para resolver el problema puede que sea un poco obvio, pero de todas maneras lo menciono.
Esencialmente me basé en utilizar la potencia del módulo Pandas antes de pasar los datos ya filtrados y corregidos a PostgreSQL.
Básicamente fui creando un DataFrame con todas las lecturas de los ficheros que poseía y sobre ese DataFrame realicé las tareas de filtrado y correción de datos que requería. Una vez con los datos a punto pasé todo el DataFrame a PostgreSQL.
Saludos y hasta la vista